# Winexe error NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE executing script from Linux to Windows Server 2012

Tags: linux, networking, remote, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed winexe on my linux machine. I want to use it to execute some script on a Windows Servre 2012. It doesn't work, the error is `NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE`.

I've followed this guide to install winexe: https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Winexe

I've enabled `SMBv1` and `SMBv2` on Windows Server.

The script I'm trying to execute is:

```
./bin/winexe -U administrator%pwd4administrator //serverip "cmd.exe"
```

I've done nothing else. Am i missing something?

The workgroup on my linux machine (on `/etc/samba/smb.conf`) is `MYGROUP`, the workgroup on Windows server is `WORKGROUP`.

I tryed this way:

```
./bin/winexe -U administrator%pwd4administrator -W WORKGROUP //serverip "cmd.exe"
```

But nothing changed.

Comment: have you tried DOMAIN/administrator (not the actual word DOMAIN of course but only you know what DOMAIN should be)

Comment: What do you mean? I've tryed with "./Administrator", because the machine its in his own domain

Comment: "it's own domain" ... so, its domain is "."? i think you'll find it's not ... it's possibly the "Computer Name" or whatever microsoft calls it